# Trouble installing Particle js

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I've tried several different methods in trying to install Particle JS but can't seem to get them to work. When the page loads, the div that's supposed to contain the animated effect is there and in the right place, but there are no particles. I'm not the savviest with JavaScript, as I'm starting to get into web design more.

My source code is at https://github.com/nickhom3/UC-2.0 (https://nickhom3.github.io/UC-2.0/).

I've tried the setup guides here:

1. https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js
2. https://redstapler.co/particles-js-tutorial/
3. https://alligator.io/js/background-effects-particlesjs/

I can't figure out if I just didn't set things up right and hopefully somebody can help me fix this.

Comment: Hi - Welcome to stackoverflow :)

I see that you have a bunch of 404's on your JS's. So somehow your javascript is not loading. I think that's where the problem lies. Maybe you can look at the path and url?

And an edit maybe you can try to attach it to an event, such as a document ready? or a window load?

Comment: @MagalieLinda thanks for responding! I didn't think to look into the console. So the guides to have me run a script, located in app.js, but it seems that "particlesJS" is not defined. I'm not really sure what this means and where I should go to define it.

Comment: Hi Nick, you also see 404 - it basically means your javascript files can't be found. I don't really know why, have you tried using a cdn? https://cdnjs.com/libraries/particlesjs